# Can I hide routes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

How does GitHub do the "star" button without naming a route for it? I'm assuming there is no route for it, since when I hover over the "star" button, no link shows up. [image: GitHub star]

And then some AJAX magic, it returns back to "unstar". How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's AJAX magic. There is a route. Open the browser console, inspect the Network activity when you toggle it.

Comment: `<button class="minibutton with-count js-toggler-target star-button" aria-label="Unstar this repository" title="Unstar skcript/SHRINK">
        <span class="octicon octicon-star"></span>
        Unstar
</button>`

So this is the HTML code when I inspect the element. How does it not appear at the bottom of the browser as a link? Sorry if this is a noob question. I'd love to understand how they did this.

Comment: The browser status automatically shows the href of anchor tags if the developer hasn't used some JavaScript to forcefully show something else. Otherwise, there is JavaScript listening for click events to that button and performing whatever action it needs to.